# Why my home screen wallpaper is damaged?

Tags: android

Hi i am coding to set a Home Screen Wallpaper. It's working fine. But my image pixel is totally damaged and then my wallpaper is not fit with the actual size of the home screen. I am try to workout different size of images. Unfortunately it's not working for me. How to solve it.

My code is here

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.newimage);
Bitmap wallpaper = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();           
try 
{
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaper);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My Screenshot Original Image
[image]

My Screenshot Android Emulator Home Screen
[image]

Why my original image is damaged here.
How to display `My Original Image` based on the `Emulator Size`.

Comment: What do you mean by "My image pixel is totally damaged"? What code have you written, and what have you tried?

Comment: Why not add a screenshot, then we will get a better idea what the problem is.

Comment: @mariomario Now i am added my screenshot.

Comment: Give me any idea, How do fix width and height of the wallpaper.

Comment: Could you add another image or mock up with how you would like your image to show on the emulator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.newimage);
Bitmap wallpaper_source = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();           
try {
    int w = wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
    int h = wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
    int x = (w-wallpaper_source.getWidth())/2;
    int y = (h-wallpaper_source.getHeight())/2;
    Bitmap wallpaper = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(wallpaper);
    c.drawBitmap(wallpaper_source, x,y, null);
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaper);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This code is working super. I expect result as for example if the Image Size is `72*72` or `1200*1200` and then the Emulator size is `480*480`. So I need to change the Image Size as `480*480` without damaging pixel and then set to the Wallpaper. Thanks.

Comment: if this is an answer you're accepting then give this guy his bounty!

Answer (score 0):

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(activity);
    BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    myOptions.inDither = true;
    myOptions.inScaled = false;
    myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    myOptions.inDither = false;
    myOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap preparedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity
            .getApplication().getResources(), R.drawable.newimage, myOptions);
    try 
    {
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(preparedBitmap);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is what I use to make my images scale well without crazy lines running across - you could try this for wallpaper - not sure if it works , let me know.